# Get the Value of input text on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input box like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="getProductqty('+this.value+')"
    placeholder="0" id="'+productSizeId+'">
```

And i am trying to get the value of the input field by the `getProductqty()` function.

I have tried like this

```
    function getProductqty(productQnty)
    {
        console.log(productQnty);
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        console.log($this.value );
    }
```

From the both i found the undefined value. Please any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're passing a hardcoded string as the argument. I have difficulty believing that it is coming out as undefined. (Possibly you are generating that HTML with embedded JS using PHP or something. You need to provide a real [mcve])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass the reference `this` to `getProductqty` function and get the value of input like

```js
function getProductqty(input){
  console.log(input.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" onblur = "getProductqty(this)" placeholder="0" id="productSizeId">
```

Comment: When you pass `this` to the callback, it gets the control, not the event. `getProductqty(event)` should change to `getProductqty(control)` or `getProductqty(element)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `this` and get it in the function and access the `value` property on it. Or if you want to pass `this.value` then you dont need all those extra `+` and `'`

```js
function getProductqty(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" onblur = "getProductqty(this.value)" placeholder="0">
```